# Adding a column to a file csv using awk passing only column index

Tags: python-3.x, csv, awk

I'm having problems with this exercise.

- I've a string array and have to add those array into a column.
- I've a CSV file and know only the column index.
- I need also to start input fro row 12 until the array is finished.

I've tried this in Python:

```
index = 0 
col = "17"
while index < len(packages):
    cmdw = "awk -F \"\t\" -V OFS=\"\t\" -v col=" + col + " -v dato=" + packages[index] + " '{$col=$dato};' 1540476113.gt.tie "
    print("eseguo il comando ",cmd)
    os.system(cmdw)
    print("comando eseguito")
    index = index + 1

print("packages aggiunti!")
```

Sample data input file:

```
# TIE output version: 1.0 (text format)
# generated by: . -a ndping_1.0 -r /home/giuseppe/Scrivania/gruppo30/1540476113/traffic.pcap 

# Working Mode: off-line
# Session Type: biflow
# 1 plugins enabled: ndping 

# begin trace interval: 1540476116.42434

# begin TIE Table
# id    src_ip      dst_ip      proto   sport   dport   dwpkts  uppkts  dwbytes upbytes t_start         t_last          app_id  sub_id  app_details confidence
17  192.168.20.105  216.58.205.42   6   50854   443 8   9   1507    1728    1540476136.698920   1540476136.879543   501 0   Google  100
26  192.168.20.105  151.101.66.202  6   40107   443 15  18  5874    1882    1540476194.196948   1540476204.641949   501 0   SSL_with_certificate    100
27  192.168.20.105  31.13.90.2  6   48133   443 10  15  4991    1598    1540476194.218949   1540476196.358946   501 0   Facebook    100
38  192.168.20.105  13.32.71.69 6   52108   443 9   12  5297    2062    1540476195.492946   1540476308.604998   501 0   SSL_with_certificate    100
0   34.246.212.92   192.168.20.105  6   443 37981   3   2   187 98  1540476116.042434   1540476189.868844   0   0   Other TCP   0
29  192.168.20.105  13.32.123.222   6   36481   443 11  15  6638    1914    1540476194.376945   1540476308.572998   501 0   SSL_with_certificate    100
31  192.168.20.105  8.8.8.8 17  1219    53  1   1   253 68  1540476194.898945   1540476194.931198   501 0   DNS 100
42  192.168.20.105  8.8.8.8 17  8339    53  1   1   198 70  1540476215.626959   1540476215.643374   501 0   DNS 100
33  192.168.20.105  8.8.8.8 17  10529   53  1   1   198 70  1540476194.960946   1540476194.977174   501 0   DNS 100
35  192.168.20.105  8.8.8.8 17  10916   53  1   1   169 64  1540476195.149943   1540476195.189064   501 0   DNS 100
44  192.168.20.105  8.8.8.8 17  11736   53  1   1   111 63  1540476217.327956   1540476217.369471   501 0   DNS 100
21  192.168.20.105  8.8.8.8 17  13249   53  1   1   102 70  1540476189.828943   1540476189.869843   501 0   DNS 100
24  192.168.20.105  8.8.8.8 17  14312   53  1   1   128 64  1540476194.150951   1540476194.166601   501 0   DNS 100
28  192.168.20.105  8.8.8.8 17  15049   53  1   1   174 67  1540476194.312946   1540476194.354500   501 0   DNS 100
37  192.168.20.105  8.8.8.8 17  17362   53  1   1   75  59  1540476195.428947   1540476195.468915   501 0   DNS 100
39  192.168.20.105  8.8.8.8 17  25274   53  1   1   258 63  1540476195.683944   1540476195.699796   501 0   DNS 100
25  192.168.20.105  8.8.8.8 17  26608   53  1   1   122 64  1540476194.191945   1540476194.207576   501 0   DNS 100
14  192.168.20.105  8.8.8.8 17  35680   53  1   1   120 59  1540476133.452918   1540476133.486316   501 0   DNS 100
18  192.168.20.105  8.8.8.8 17  43833   53  1   1   118 72  1540476136.868920   1540476136.902531   501 0   DNS 100
4   192.168.20.105  8.8.8.8 17  43919   53  1   1   93  61  1540476126.806916   1540476126.822800   501 0   DNS 100
2   192.168.20.105  8.8.8.8 17  51340   53  1   1   141 63  1540476124.935913   1540476124.967768   501 0   DNS 100
3   192.168.20.105  8.8.8.8 17  64815   53  1   1   141 63  1540476124.974914   1540476125.006749   501 0   DNS 100
30  192.168.20.105  216.58.198.14   6   48980   443 4   2   1093    884 1540476194.835944   1540476195.102945   0   0   Other TCP   0
```

I would be able to add to this file a new colum after the 12 row of header

Comment: Can you please share the sample output?

Comment: Check the `-V` instead of `-v` in your awk command.

Comment: super easy in `awk` (probably 1 line of code). Please simplify your problem data set. Won't a 3 line header and 4 columns of data (with 3-4 rows) illustrate the problem? AND we need to see if you want to insert new column at front, back or in the middle, so please show required output from sample input. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly read the file in python, skip the 12 line header and append required values to last column.

I have just printed the output in below code you can write it to a new file if required.

```
    index = 0 
    col = "17"
    header_len = 0 
    packages = [ "dato =" + str(i) for i in range(100)] # created dummy list, replace it with original one
    with open("input_file.txt",'r+') as f :
        for line in f:
            if header_len >= 12 and index < len(packages): # comparing header length and remaining index in list.
                print("{}\t{}".format(line.rstrip('\n'),packages[index]))
                index+=1

            else:
                print(line)
                header_len+=1
```

sample output :

```
# TIE output version: 1.0 (text format)
# generated by: . -a ndping_1.0 -r /home/giuseppe/Scrivania/gruppo30/1540476113/traffic.pcap

# Working Mode: off-line
# Session Type: biflow
# 1 plugins enabled: ndping

# begin trace interval: 1540476116.42434

# begin TIE Table
# id    src_ip      dst_ip      proto   sport   dport   dwpkts  uppkts  dwbytes upbytes t_start         t_last          app_id  sub_id  app_details confidence
17  192.168.20.105  216.58.205.42   6   50854   443 8   9   1507    1728    1540476136.698920   1540476136.879543   501 0   Google  100
26  192.168.20.105  151.101.66.202  6   40107   443 15  18  5874    1882    1540476194.196948   1540476204.641949   501 0   SSL_with_certificate    100 dato =0
27  192.168.20.105  31.13.90.2  6   48133   443 10  15  4991    1598    1540476194.218949   1540476196.358946   501 0   Facebook    100 dato =1
38  192.168.20.105  13.32.71.69 6   52108   443 9   12  5297    2062    1540476195.492946   1540476308.604998   501 0   SSL_with_certificate    100     dato =2
0   34.246.212.92   192.168.20.105  6   443 37981   3   2   187 98  1540476116.042434   1540476189.868844   0   0   Other TCP   0       dato =3
29  192.168.20.105  13.32.123.222   6   36481   443 11  15  6638    1914    1540476194.376945   1540476308.572998   501 0   SSL_with_certificate    100 dato =4
```